# change background color of active menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

```html
<div class="row">
      <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
        <div class = "navbar-header">
          <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
            <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="helpline-phone">
            <a href="tel:000000">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone pull-right visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><router-link to="/en">Home</router-link></li>
            <li><router-link to="/about/en">About</router-link></li>
            <li class = "dropdown">
              <a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                Information
                <b class = "caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                <li><router-link to="/usefulLinks/en">Useful Links</router-link></li>
                <li><router-link to="/counsellingCenters/en">Counselling Centers</router-link></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><router-link to="/videos/en">Videos</router-link></li>
            <li><router-link to="/articles">Articles</router-link></li>
            <li><router-link to="/howItWorks">How it works</router-link></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="pull-right lang">
            <select name="educationOption" class="selectpicker" v-on:change="changeLanguageToMarathi" v-model="mySelectedLang">
              
               <option :value="MR">MR</option>
               <option>EN</option>
             
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="contact pull-right hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
            <a href="tel:000000">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
              <span>000000</span>(10AM to 6PM)
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

hello i am usng bootstrap & vuejs to design my project.i want to change the background color current active menu.i am using bootstrap active class.but it showing me the first menu active.when i click to the another menu it dont set or change color of the clicked active menu.
i want to change background of the current active menu.

Comment: where is you javascript?

Comment: please do not make snippets without all the necessary code needed to reproduce your problem ( css + javascript included )

Comment: i didnt write any javascript for it.

Comment: and the CSS ? please share it so we can reproduce your problem